# How to get a variable's output in html value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, dropdown

I have the following code to display the last path of previous page.

```
var ref = document.referrer;
var pElements = ref.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/');
var last = pElements[pElements.length - 1]
```

Now what i want to do is to change the dropdown-list in the new site according to the value of **last** since it contains 4 options with values which are equal to **last** (you can come from page a,b,c or d)

```
$("[value='last']").attr('selected',true)
```

I tried this but the dropdown won't change the select according to **last**

Hopefully you get what i mean… Sorry for my bad english. But i just want to output **last** in the last code-snipped, like when i come from **a** the code would look like:

```
$("[value='a']").attr('selected',true)
```

and the dropdown would select **a**

Comment: and use `.prop('selected', 'true');` instead `'.attr('selected',true)'`

Comment: Does not work  - the console outputs [] . The attr-way works when i type in by hand. Could it be case-sensitive?

Comment: Ohh! It IS Case-sensitive… Now how can i change the output of $last so that the first character would be captial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your selector `$("[value='last']")` you are not evaluating `last`, you are literally taking the option that has a value of `"last"`.

Instead, make your selector take the actual value of last.

```
$("[value='"+last+"']")
```

**Important gotcha** - you will need to make sure to make all the other options don't have the selected attribute by clearing that attribute beforehand. jQuery will do this for you if you use `.val(last)` on the select element.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how to change the first character  of my + last + to uppercase? I guess that the dropdown is case sensitive, since  it contains options with capital first letters, like Test and not test

Comment: I'd recommend changing the value you need so that the first character is lowercase. But if you can't, then you can do `last = last[0].toUpperCase() + last.substring(1)` before you use it in your selector. This assumes your string is at least 2 characters long, which should be safe enough if the value is always a path.

Comment: Woaaa so excited :) The finish is in sight! But you've written ToUpperCase, should be toUpperCase

Comment: I'm chosing your answer as the right answer. Wasn't easy to decide since both answers (yours and Rory's) work - but for me your bonus-answer helped me in my situation to get my problem solved! Thanks mate i owe you a beer (next time you come to germany, write me :p )

Comment: Haha, sure - next time I'm in the Northern Hemisphere

Comment: I feel guilty now - I didn't even pick up the .prop() problem

Answer (score 3):

To set the selected option of a `select` element, use `val()`. Try this:

```
$("select").val(last);
```

Obviously, you may need to make the selector a little more specific than that to suit your needs.

Comment: When i do this my Dropdown changes to blank

Comment: Does the value in the `last` variable *exactly* match the value of an `option` in your `select`? Seeing your HTML would help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: It was my fault, didn't know that a dropdown is case sensitive in this matter.

Comment: hey rory, sorry i've chosen binderbound's answer since he gave me a solution to my followed problem with the case sensitive-thing. Your answer works too, dont get mad pls :)